# RoR - Associations into practise - forms (View)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I'm learning Ruby on Rails.

I'm using some associations (has_many :through, ...)

But i'm having some problems with it when i'm combining my views.

How exactly do i combine these nested forms? Can i do this with partial forms and where do i have to write extra code for this? I have seen examples only use the "view" and others also edit the controller....

An example would be very nice :-)

Edit:

My "little" personal project is about movies, i'll show you the model.
I want all the database fields in ONE form...

Where do i begin? => partial forms and put it together afterwards?
Or from scratch?

table: boxMovies
[
 name:string
]

table: boxMovies_movies
[
 boxMovies_id : string
 movies_id : string
 part : integer
]

table: movies
[
 name : string
 description : string
]

table: movieNews
[
 movie_id : int (FK)
 title : string
 news : text
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:  [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#M002132), I can give you a more detailed answer if you be more specific.